# Using Xpath return text that is positioned after the last comma

Tags: xpath

Using xpath, I want to return the value 000078 & 000077 from the below xml. The text for "Entity" tag can be 2 comma separated values or 3 or more. I always want the last value.

```
<Parent ID="123">
    <SubParent ID="1">
        <Name>Modem</Name>
        <Entity>000006,000069,000078</Entity>
    </SubParent>
    <SubParent ID="2">  
        <Name>Modem</Name>
        <Entity>000006,000077</Entity>
    </SubParent>
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath is a selection language, not a string processing (or general purpose programming) language, and you can only select from the distinct nodes in your document.

The nodes that contain the values you are looking for are two text nodes, `'000006,000069,000078'`  and `'000006,000077'`, so `//Entity/text()` (or `//Entity`) is the closest you can get with XPath alone.

Any further string processing, like pulling out the substring after the last comma, must be done in the host language.

---

This is one of the examples that show that storing opaque strings that contain multiple data points (like comma-separated values) in XML is a bad idea.

This is how your XML *should* look like.

```
<Parent ID="123">
   <SubParent ID="1">
            <Name>Modem</Name>
            <Entity>000006</Entity>
            <Entity>000069</Entity>
            <Entity>000078</Entity>
   </SubParent>
   <SubParent ID="2">  
            <Name>Modem</Name>
            <Entity>000006</Entity>
            <Entity>000077</Entity>
   </SubParent>
</Parent>
```

because now you would easily be able to select `//Entity[last()]/text()` and get exactly two nodes.